# oop login register system , it logs in, it gets values from database but doesnt insert data

Tags: php, mysql, oop, pdo

guys first of all all this code here is a fork from codecourse tutorials in youtube! the thing is that in ubuntu 14.04 its running like a charm with no problems but when i try to use this in ubuntu 16.04 i get error in register function and i dont know how i can fix this!!
first of all in ubuntu 14.04 i used php (5.5-5.6) im not sure, mysql is 5.6 instead of ubuntu 16.4 that i use php 7 and mysql 5.7!

the error that im getting is this:

> Exception: Sorry, there was a problem creating your account;  in
>   /var/www/html/classes/User.php:35 Stack trace: #0
>   /var/www/html/register.php(47): User->create(Array) #1 {main}

thanks in advance you guys!!! if you need another script tell me to reply it!!

DB.php (database class)

```
class DB {
private static $_instance = null;
private $_pdo,
        $_query,
        $_error = false,
        $_results,
        $_count = 0;

private function __construct() {
    try {
        $this->_pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=' . Config::get('mysql/host') . ';dbname=' . Config::get('mysql/db'), Config::get('mysql/username'), Config::get('mysql/password'));
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        die($e->getMessage());
    }
}

public static function getInstance() {
    if(!isset(self::$_instance)) {
        self::$_instance = new DB();
    }
    return self::$_instance;
}

public function query($sql, $params = array()) {
    $this->_error = false;

    if($this->_query = $this->_pdo->prepare($sql)) {
        $x = 1;
        if(count($params)) {
            foreach($params as $param) {
                $this->_query->bindValue($x, $param);
                $x++;
            }
        }

        if($this->_query->execute()) {
            $this->_results = $this->_query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
            $this->_count = $this->_query->rowCount();
        } else {
            $this->_error = true;
        }
    }

    return $this;
}

public function action($action, $table, $where = array()) {
    if(count($where) === 3) {
        $operators = array('=', '>', '<', '>=', '<=');

        $field = $where[0];
        $operator = $where[1];
        $value = $where[2];

        if(in_array($operator, $operators)) {
            $sql = "{$action} FROM {$table} WHERE {$field} {$operator} ?";

            if(!$this->query($sql, array($value))->error()) {
                return $this;
            }
        }

    }

    return false;
}

public function insert($table, $fields = array()) {
    $keys = array_keys($fields);
    $values = null;
    $x = 1;

    foreach($fields as $field) {
        $values .= '?';
        if ($x < count($fields)) {
            $values .= ', ';
        }
        $x++;
    }

    $sql = "INSERT INTO {$table} (`" . implode('`, `', $keys) . "`) VALUES ({$values})";

    if(!$this->query($sql, $fields)->error()) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

public function update($table, $id, $fields) {
    $set = '';
    $x = 1;

    foreach($fields as $name => $value) {
        $set .= "{$name} = ?";
        if($x < count ($fields)) {
            $set .= ', ';
        }
        $x++;
    }

    $sql = "UPDATE {$table} SET {$set} WHERE id = {$id}";

    if(!$this->query($sql, $fields)->error()) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

public function delete($table, $where) {
    return $this->action('DELETE ', $table, $where);
}

public function get($table, $where) {
    return $this->action('SELECT *', $table, $where);
}

public function results() {
    return $this->_results;
}

public function first() {
    $data = $this->results();
    return $data[0];
}

public function count() {
    return $this->_count;
}

public function error() {
    return $this->_error;
}
}
```

user.php (user class)

```
class User {
private $_db,
        $_data,
        $_sessionName,
        $_cookieName,
        $isLoggedIn;

public function __construct($user = null) {
    $this->_db = DB::getInstance();
    $this->_sessionName = Config::get('sessions/session_name');
    $this->_cookieName = Config::get('remember/cookie_name');

    if(!$user) {
        if(Session::exists($this->_sessionName)) {
            $user = Session::get($this->_sessionName);

            if($this->find($user)) {
                $this->isLoggedIn = true;
            } else {
                //Logout
            }
        }
    } else {
        $this->find($user);
    }
}

public function create($fields = array()) {
    if(!$this->_db->insert('users', $fields)) {
        throw new Exception('Sorry, there was a problem creating your account;');
    }
}

public function update($fields = array(), $id = null) {

    if(!$id && $this->isLoggedIn()) {
        $id = $this->data()->id;
    }

    if(!$this->_db->update('users', $id, $fields)) {
        throw new Exception('There was a problem updating');
    }
}

public function find($user = null) {
    if($user) {
        $field = (is_numeric($user)) ? 'id' : 'username';
        $data = $this->_db->get('users', array($field, '=', $user));

        if($data->count()) {
            $this->_data = $data->first();
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

public function login($username = null, $password = null, $remember = false) {
    if(!$username && !$password && $this->exists()) {
        Session::put($this->_sessionName, $this->data()->id);
    } else {
        $user = $this->find($username);

        if ($user) {
            if ($this->data()->password === Hash::make($password, $this->data()->salt)) {
                Session::put($this->_sessionName, $this->data()->id);

                if ($remember) {
                    $hash = Hash::unique();
                    $hashCheck = $this->_db->get('users_session', array('user_id', '=', $this->data()->id));

                    if (!$hashCheck->count()) {
                        $this->_db->insert('users_session', array(
                            'user_id' => $this->data()->id,
                            'hash' => $hash
                        ));
                    } else {
                        $hash = $hashCheck->first()->hash;
                    }

                    Cookie::put($this->_cookieName, $hash, Config::get('remember/cookie_expiry'));
                }

                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

public function hasPermission($key) {
    $group = $this->_db->get('groups', array('id', '=', $this->data()->group));

    if($group->count()) {
        $permissions = json_decode($group->first()->permissions, true);

        return !empty($permissions[$key]);
    }

    return false;
}

public function exists() {
    return (!empty($this->_data)) ? true : false;
}

public function logout() {
    $this->_db->delete('users_session', array('user_id', '=', $this->data()->id));

    Session::delete($this->_sessionName);
    Cookie::delete($this->_cookieName);
}

public function data(){
    return $this->_data;
}

public function isLoggedIn() {
    return $this->isLoggedIn;
}
}
```

register.php (register script)

```
require_once 'core/init.php';

if (Input::exists()) {
if(Token::check(Input::get('token'))) {
    $validate = new Validate();
    $validation = $validate->check($_POST, array(
        'name' => array(
            'name' => 'Name',
            'required' => true,
            'min' => 2,
            'max' => 50
        ),
        'username' => array(
            'name' => 'Username',
            'required' => true,
            'min' => 2,
            'max' => 20,
            'unique' => 'users'
        ),
        'password' => array(
            'name' => 'Password',
            'required' => true,
            'min' => 6
        ),
        'password_again' => array(
            'required' => true,
            'matches' => 'password'
        ),
    ));

    if ($validate->passed()) {
        $user = new User();
        $salt = Hash::salt(32);

        try {
            $user->create(array(
                'name' => Input::get('name'),
                'username' => Input::get('username'),
                'password' => Hash::make(Input::get('password'), $salt),
                'salt' => $salt,
                'joined' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
                'group' => 1
            ));

            Session::flash('home', 'Welcome ' . Input::get('username') . '! Your account has been registered. You may now log in.');
            Redirect::to('index.php');
        } catch(Exception $e) {
            echo $e, '<br>';
        }
    } else {
        foreach ($validate->errors() as $error) {
            echo $error . "<br>";
        }
    }
}
}
?>

<form action="" method="post">
<div class="field">
    <label for="name">Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo escape(Input::get('name')); ?>" id="name">
</div>

<div class="field">
    <label for="username">Username</label>
    <input type="text" name="username" id="username" value="<?php echo escape(Input::get('username')); ?>">
</div>

<div class="field">
    <label for="password">Password</label>
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password">
</div>

<div class="field">
    <label for="password_again">Password Again</label>
    <input type="password" name="password_again" id="password_again" value="">
</div>

<input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo Token::generate(); ?>">
<input type="submit" value="Register">
</form>
```

init.php

```
 session_start();

$GLOBALS['config'] = array(
'mysql' => array(
    'host' => '127.0.1.1',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => '123456',
    'db' => 'db'
),
'remember' => array(
    'cookie_name' => 'hash',
    'cookie_expiry' => 604800
),
'sessions' => array(
    'session_name' => 'user',
    'token_name' => 'token'
)
);

spl_autoload_register(function($class) {
require_once 'classes/' . $class . '.php';
});

require_once 'functions/sanitize.php';

if(Cookie::exists(Config::get('remember/cookie_name')) && !Session::exists(Config::get('sessions/session_name'))) {
$hash = Cookie::get(Config::get('remember/cookie_name'));
$hashCheck = DB::getInstance()->get('users_session', array('hash', '=', $hash));

if($hashCheck->count()) {
    $user = new User($hashCheck->first()->user_id);
    $user->login();
}
}
```

Comment: Please, read [mcve]. No one will read this sheets of code.

Comment: ive experimented with print_r($sql) etc in the database & user section and it prints the queries normal! i dont know how to debug outputs except from the error message that it prints on site.. are there any tools to do that?

Comment: When you create the PDO object, set it to throw exceptions. By default it errors silently.  `$this->_pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);`  The cause of the failure should become apparent then.